# Android gridview: how to make items in a gridview load one by one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I mean, if I have 9 images adaptted in a gridview by a self-implemented adapter, how to make'em display one by one instead of showing all 9 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
Use this library to load images